# Is there a way to hide global functions in static class?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to hide global functions in static class?
I tried to create a
`static class Program{public: <ALL GLOBAL FUNCTIONS>};`

and then just change the functions calls to Program::function, yet it doesn't work as I supposed it should. Is there a different way to do that? Or is my thinking completely flawed, and it won't work that way?

Comment: Might I ask, why *would* you want to hide a *global* function?

Comment: Post the code here.

Comment: there is no way to do so because global function is not part of the class,global function is global function and if you have one then you dont want it to hide

Comment: don't be lazy and put a link to 500+ loc. Take your time and create a [MCVE] for your problem about 5 lines of code would suffice

Comment: For clearance in code. I want to create two different parts of program, one would be Program:: with functions that would be operating on memory etc., and second HaventCameUpWithIdea:: that would be operating on objects. This way I will practice code clearence in different way. (Yes, I know it is best to use .H files, yet I am practicing diffrent things, and exploring that way). @bolov thanks for your advice, I am new here, and I will follow that since the very next time.

Comment: Hide them from who or from what?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static class" in C++. What you're looking for is a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If by `static`, you mean a function that can run without an object instance, then you can bury them deep within a translation unit using an *anonymous namespace*:

```
namespace /*No name here; i.e. it's anonymous*/
{
    foo Foo(/*parameters*/)
    {
        // ToDo - code here
    }
}
```

`Foo` will not be visible to any other translation unit.